# Save pdf with enpooint POST in NEXTJS

Tags: next.js, multer

I am trying to save pdf files on local disk and other values such as name, location, etc. in the databases, however, when sending the data, it does not save the files in the /src/libs/uploadsTest directory

The code in nextjs I implemented is this

```
import multer from 'multer'; // Multer for handling file uploads
import path from 'path'; // Path module for manipulating file paths
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"; // NextResponse for sending responses in Next.js
import db from "@/libs/prisma"; // Prisma for interacting with the database

export async function POST(request) {
  try {
    // Configure Multer for file storage
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        // Define the upload directory path
        const uploadDir = path.join(process.cwd(),"/src/libs/uploadsTest");
        console.log("Ruta:"+uploadDir);
        // Create the upload directory if it doesn't exist
        fs.mkdirSync(uploadDir, { recursive: true });
        // Set the upload directory as the destination
        cb(null, uploadDir);
      },
      // Define the filename for the uploaded file
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        // Use a unique identifier (e.g., UUID) as the filename
        cb(null, uuidv4());
      }
    });

    // Configure Multer to handle file uploads
    const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('pdfFiles', 2);  

    // Parse the request body as JSON
    const requestBody = await request.json();
    // Create a new record in the database with the parsed request body
    await db.Authorizations.create({
      data: requestBody
    });

    // Return a JSON response indicating success
    return NextResponse.json({ msje: "Data added successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    // If an error occurs, return a JSON response indicating an error
    return NextResponse.json({ msje: "Error" });
  }
}
```